# traversing a doubly-linked list and insert at its end (C++)

Tags: c++, list, insert

I have to face this problem: I have a doubly linked list and I have to make insertion at the tail. My list is made of *Node*s such as

```
struct Node {
    int val;        // contains the value
    Node * next;    // pointer to the next element in the list
    Node * prev;    // pointer to the previous element in the list
};
```

and my class list declares only

```
private:
    Node * first;           // Pointer to the first (if any) element in the list
```

at first.

Now, I wrote such a method for inserting:

```
void List::insert(int n){
    Node * tmp = new Node;
    tmp->val = n;
    tmp->next = 0;

    if (!first) {
        first = tmp;
    }
    else {
        Node * p = new Node;
        p = first;
        while (p->next) {
            p = p->next;
        }
        p->next = tmp;
        tmp->prev = p;
    } 
};
```

and if I take several numbers from cin (say, 1 2 3 4), I call *insert* but I end up not having all the elements I wanted to store. I have only *first* and *tmp*, which contains the last number from the input (e.g. 4).

I struggle to figure out what's wrong - my first suggestion is variable scope. 
Or is there anything wrong during the pointer setting?

OBS: I'd use a tail pointer of course, but the aim is traversing the list.

Any feedback is really appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: If you're not inserting in the first position, you're allocating two `Node`s. This is a memory leak. (But it's not the cause of your problems.) `Node* p = first;` would fix it.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks, it sounds like a great suggestion! I'm very basic in this, and I'm trying to use the debugger inside Xcode to check what happens to my variables. I do read immediately your link.

Comment: @molbdnilo, isn't it what I do in the successive line? I first create a new node and then I make it point to my first one.

Comment: @MattiaPaterna You create a `Node` and point `p` to that `Node` (the `Node` doesn't point anywhere; it's just a `Node` That Has No Name). Then you point `p` to a different `Node` (the same node that `first` points to) instead. When you do that, the newly created `Node` is lost forever. (It's a good idea to get some paper and draw the pointers and what they point to. Drawing on paper is a much better way of debugging pointers than any debugger I've seen.)

Comment: How are you determining what the list contains? Do you have an output function or are you traversing it by hand in the debugger? Adding an output function [produces the expected result](http://ideone.com/TyoHyX).

Comment: @molbdnilo I have a print method that looks like exactly as yours, but I take the input via cin in this way: `while (cin >> n) {l.insert(n)}`. But yes, I can see your solution works as mine should.

Comment: @MattiaPaterna "My" solution is yours without the memory leak. It's very strange if it doesn't work for you.